# why there is space in the borders of the table?

Tags: tables

I used the following code to draw the table, however, there is blank space in the border. the lines are not connected. May someone help me?

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    shapes.geometric,
    positioning,
    fit,
    calc
}
\usepackage{array}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\newcommand*{\Shift}{0.6ex}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, proof} % mathabx,
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

% GRAPHICS

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning,shapes,patterns}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{scalefnt}
 \begin{table}[h]
  \centering

    \begin{tabular}%{@{}p{0.7in}c@{\hspace{0.5em}}c@{\hspace{0.5em}}c@{\hspace{0.5em}}c}
    {| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.7in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.7in} |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.7in} |}
    \toprule
    {\small{Response Time}} & \small{Availability} & \small{Throughput} \\
    \midrule
    $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n q(\si)$  &  $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n q(\si)$  & $\min\limits_{i=1}^n q(\si)$   \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
\caption{Aggregation Function}
  \label{tab:compositionalStructure}%
\end{table}
```

![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't said (please *always* post complete documents showing all packages used) but you are using `booktabs`. `booktabs` as an explicit, documented design aim, is incompatible with vertical rules. You need to choose to either have vertical rules or use that package.

Comment: nope, booktabs is not using, I have posted all the package here. Anyway can edit it to show the line connecting together?

Comment: @william007 Your example is still not a complete document, if I add `\documentclass{article}` and define `\si` so that it runs without error then the log file confirms `booktabs` is being used `(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty` (`ctable` loads `booktabs`)

Comment: i guess you are right, i draw a new table, and it works. Those toprule, midrule, etc. are the culprit.